# Xamarin forms - force show back button

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a tabbed page, with 4 navigation pages in it.

I want the back button to show on the 'home' page of each of the navigation pages, and then I want to override the event so if its clicked on the home page it will go back to the previous tab (i'll keep track of the tabs they have been on myself).

I'm trying to show the back button on the root of each navigation page with this:

```
NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(this, true);
```

But the back button doesn't seem to show up. How do I force the back button appear?

Answer (score 8):

I think the best way is to not go for a back button. Remove it and add your custom button with the functionality you are looking for. The reason for this is because you're doing totally something different where the NavigationPage is designed for.